# Understanding the development of mathematical model from an equation to another equations in a paper

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I read the paper ["Flexible Camera Calibration By Viewing a Plane From Unknown Orientations"](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/papers/zhan99.pdf) for Zhang, but I didn't understand how did he developed the mathematical equations from **equation 2** to **equations 3 and 4**, can you please explain that to me.

**Thanks in advance**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $h_1 = \lambda A r_1$ and $h_2 = \lambda A r_2$. Thus $r_1 = \lambda^{-1} A^{-1} h_1$ and $r_2 = \lambda^{-1} A^{-1} h_2$.

Orthogonality of $r_1$ and $r_2$ implies
$$0 = r_1^\top r_2 = \lambda^{-2} h_1^\top A^{-T} A^{-1} h_2.$$

The fact that $r_1$ and $r_2$ have norm $1$ implies
$$1 = r_1^\top r_1 = \lambda^{-2} h_1 A^{-T} A^{-1} h_1$$
$$1 = r_2^\top r_2 = \lambda^{-2} h_2 A^{-T} A^{-1} h_2$$